# FAQ not mentioning allowance of one question per 6 months during question ban?

Tags: support, post-ban, obsolete-information

As [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/350567) is currently written, the only way to lift a post ban is by fixing your existing posts - including deleted ones.

However, various users - mostly high rep users on MSE - claims that you're allowed **one question every six months** if you're banned from asking. And if you managed to ask a well-received question, your ban may be lifted automatically. If you failed again, go wait another six months.

I'm curious why this information isn't added into [the FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86997/350567). Is it wrong? Is there any special reason not to add it?

Comment: Because no one ever edited the post to include it. Really that simple. It is explicitly mentioned in the [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

Comment: @animuson I flagged it for mod attention.

Comment: @animuson so maybe it's time to unlock that faq and let us edit when needed? It's ridiculous we need to plead then wait weeks and months for important data to be added when we can add it to any other faq. And to prevent abuse by low rep users just remove the CW from the answer, thus making it editable only by 2k rep users. Really that simple. :-)

Comment: @ShadowWizard The problem wasn't with edits, but with the excessive number of comments that got posted there from users who disagree or want help, yada ya. Not being CW does nothing to prevent that.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Note the reason for the lock? "High amount of off-topic comments generated." People would keep complaining about their bans in comments if it's unlocked.

Comment: @animuson If comments are the sole reason for the lock, what about unlocking it and let the community (espetially the Tavern room) handle the comment with flags? I'm sure we can do it well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

It looks like [*Shog9*♦ has updated it a few hours ago.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/86998/revisions)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [comment by @animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/303237/faq-not-mentioning-allowance-of-one-question-per-6-months-during-question-bam#comment986045_303237) it appears:

> no one ever edited the post to include it. Really that simple. It is
>   explicitly mentioned in the [help center article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans).

where it says:

> **Does the ban last forever?**
>
> If you're unable to improve your existing questions, you'll get the
>   chance to ask a new one 6 months after your last question. If that
>   question is positively received, you may be able to continue asking
>   questions; if not, then the ban will be reinstated.

I think [What can I do when getting "We are no longer accepting questions/answers from this account"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86997) should be updated with this information but with the post locked that can only be done by one of this site's moderators (i.e. an SE staff member).